# How can I import "opencv" library in anaconda spyder on windows

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed OpenCv library through this line "pip install opencv-python" and it is successfully installed, but I am trying to import it through: "import cv2" and it gives me an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' 
please help me!

Comment: There could be a number of issues here. First are you using a virtual env, then pip global vs local can be a issue? In general check which pip you are using, check where the library got saved to, and then check which python intepretor you are using, if your using a ide check what is configured there. Check the pythonpath and  python home env variables, which again will differ in linux and windows.The place where the libirary got installed should come up when you do ```print (sys.path)```

Answer (score 0):

If your pip is installed with any other python version than conda, it won't work.

Option 1) Install pip with conda python

Run `conda create -n venv_name` and `source activate venv_name`, where venv_name is the name of your virtual environment.

Run `conda install pip`. This will install pip to your venv directory.

Option 2) Run `conda install opencv`